# Styling the listview to hide the small gap between items in a listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a listview and what I want to do is to to stye the list view in such a way that we dont see each item in the list in a "box"(the default way in which listview) appears.I have applied some css but still there is a small gap between each list items.Please help me in solving this.

This is the css i have used

```
    .list li{
                border-width:-5px !important;
                border-top-width:0px !important;
                background:#cccccc;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

A sample here - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvp9j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following css code (you can remove the `border-width` and `border-top-width` rule):

```
.ui-li {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uZY5C/).

Answer (score 1):

Setting `border-top: 0` isn't a god option if you're using borders on your list. Instead, you can set the space between the items like this:

```
.ui-li {
    margin-bottom: -1px !important;
}
```